# Find version where specific attribute has changed in papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the [Papertrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) in my project and have searched extensively to try and find how to do the following.

What I'd like to do is find the version of my object where a specific attribute came to be a specific value i.e.

`object.versions.where(attribute: "value")`

Does anyone know if this is even possible with Papertrail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PaperTrail 12.1 you can do

```ruby
object.versions.where_object_changes_to(attribute: "value")
```

Answer (score 11):

The following gets all the versions where `attribute` became `value` (which in most apps is probably around 1):

```
object.versions.
       map(&:object_changes).
       map{|a| YAML::load a}.
       select{|a| (a[:attribute] || [])[1]=='value'}
```

Result would be something like:

```
[{"attribute"=>[nil, "value"],
  "updated_at"=>[2015-01-02 12:20:36 UTC, 2015-01-02 12:20:56 UTC]}]
```

The `updated_at[1]` value indicates when `attribute` became `value`.

Getting the id of the Version can be built upon the provided code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my original question. Though for speed of processing (i.e. database queries etc.) my original approach remains my favoured one.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I've concluded this is not possible out-of-the-box in paper_trail.

What I ended up doing was, when one of the specific attributes was updated, save a flag in a separate [metadata column](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata) in the Versions table.

Then I can search against these columns in the future to find out when that specific attribute changed.

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option for those who don't want to use a separate metadata column:

```
def version_where_attribute_changed_to(attribute_name, attribute_value)
  versions.select do |version|
    object_changes = YAML.load version.object_changes
    (object_changes[attribute_name.to_s] || [])[1] == attribute_value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for versions where a specified attribute changed to or from any value, you can use the below:

```rb
@object.versions
  .map(&:changeset)
  .select{|a| a["attribute"].present?}
```